# Mousewheel Delta value always 120

Tags: wpf, mouse, mousewheel

I am creating an application in WPF that uses the mousewheel to zoom in/out an image. The amount of zooming is based on the amount of mouse wheel turning.

The problem is that the Delta value is always 120, as explained in MSDN. So, even if I turn the wheel 1 notch or 5 notches it will always be 120. Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to handle the [PreviewMouseWheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousewheel.aspx) event.  The delta for each event will be +/-120, but you will get one event for each "notch" of the wheel.

Comment: Interesting explanation about the reason for that: http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/10/26/677-why-the-standard-mouse-wheel-delta-is-120/

Comment: I guess then its worth noting that a different device might have a different delta based on wheel precision, but that delta will always be the same on each event.

Comment: To anyone who reached this issue, I recently tested `PreviewMouseWheel` event on Windows 10 and found that the delta is a multiples of +/-120 and so there is no noticeable difference from that of `MouseWheel` event.

Answer (score 1):

The above statements about ***the value always being +/-120*** are not always correct.

If you rotate the wheel **slowly**, the value is indeed +/-120,
but than, if you rotate the wheel **fast**, the value becomes +/-240.

I'm guessing that there *may be other values* too (haven't tested it, yet)...

Answer (score 0):

John Myczek gave the basically right answser. I should add that if you turn the wheel fast enough, you will notice that the delta is lager than 120 or smaller than -120. It will be a multiples of +/-120. So you'd better do some division in the handle of PreviewMouseWheel event.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int step = 0;
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
     
        if(e.Delta>0)
                step++;
        else if(e.Delta<0)
            step--;
        this.Text = "Step:-" + step.ToString();
        
    }
```